# Is there a way to use bootstrap 3.0 plugins with jQuery.noConflict()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are currently loading 2 different versions of jQuery on our page, 1.4.2 and 1.10.1. 
The $ and window.jQuery objects are currently pointing to 1.4.2.

We are using noConflict() with version 1.10.1 to set it to $jq1:

```
var $jq1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Is there any way to get Bootstrap 3.0 plugins to automatically use $jq1 instead of $ or window.jQuery?

Comment: [Twitter Bootstrap source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/collapse.js) is referring to `window.jQuery`. Maybe you can try to alter this variable before loading plugins, and switch back after?

Comment: Easy solution - stop using 2 different versions of jQuery on your page. The problem you're having now will be the least of your worries if you don't.

Comment: I wish I could, since that would be really easy, but there is a LOT of legacy code on the same page which still requires to run. I will try do let Bootstrap load using window.jQuery and then run the noConflict() function after bootstrap has loaded.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you load the bootstrap JS straight after loading jQuery version 1.10.1 and then put jQuery into no conflict mode, it should work.

e.g.:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load any Bootsrap JS files before calling jQuery.noConflict()  -->
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
// Put jQuery 1.10.2 into noConflict mode.
var $jq1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- This can be before or after the above -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`jQuery.noConflict(true)` will reassign both `$` and `jQuery` to their previous values so it doesn't matter if version 1.4.2 is loaded first or not.

It does mean your users will be downloading jQuery twice though and you will need to remember if to use `$jq1` or `$` when doing anything with jQuery.

Comment: if i use var $jq1 = jQuery.noConflict(true). can i use alert($jq1("#id").val())??? guide me.

Comment: Yes, `$jq1` will be jQuery version 1.10.2 and `$` will be 1.4.2

Comment: But why $jq1 for version 1.10.2. Just because of version 1.10.2 is loaded earlier.

Comment: The version of jQuery loaded when `jQuery.noConflict` was called in the above example was 1.10.2 so that's what `$jq1` will be set to.

Comment: Briliant, Thanks for help

Comment: It worked for me but just wondering why did it work? Any explanation of it.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the explanation that the user "ajpiano" provided at https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page:

```
<script src='jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>
<script>
    var jq132 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script>
    var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Load the Older Version of Jquery.

Then your Boostrap js,css everthing goes here.
Finally add this.,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $versionNumberJ1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Then, use like this.,

```
<script>
  $versionNumberJ1 ( function() {
    $versionNumberJ1 ( "#tabsModal" ).tabs();
  } );
  </script>
```