# How to maintain noConflict and include 2 versions of jQuery in Bootstrap 3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm modifying the UI of an old project which uses Flexigrid and Bootstrap 3.2.  Flexigrid depends on jQuery 1.4.1 and Bootstrap 3 requires jQuery 1.9.0 or higher.

I tried using the older version of jQuery with Bootstrap but it breaks; likewise I tried using the newer version with Flexigrid.. it breaks.

I'm wondering if I can include both versions and force Bootstrap to use jQuery.noConflict somehow?

**EDIT:**
Since we had a lot of js code which relied upon jQuery 1.4.1, I did this:
Added both versions of jQuery to the page (1.4.1 and 1.9.1) in the following order:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>
    var $jQuery1_9 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script src="/js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<!-- Include other js files here -->
```

Now, everything works fine (so far!). You may also find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573074/is-there-a-way-to-use-bootstrap-3-0-plugins-with-jquery-noconflict) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand TB jQuery is already included, you need to make a reference for flexigrid library in other way.

```
<!-- load jQuery Flexigrid library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//path to flexigrid library"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jQuery_flexgrid = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Then you can use jQuery_flexgrid variable to fire jQuery functions and $ (dollar) sign for TB jQuery.

Comment: How can I tell Flexigrid to use `jQuery_flexgrid `?

Comment: Are you adding flexigrid manually ? In other words, Are you firing any flexigrid functions ?

Comment: I use `$("#my_div").flexigrid()`

Comment: you can use $jQuery_flexgrid variable instead of dollar($).  $jQuery_flexgrid("#my_div").flexigrid() will work.